# In node.html.twig, how do I use the readmore flag?

Tags: 8, theming

In node.html.twig the instructions clearly state:

```
 * - readmore: Flag for more state. Will be true if the teaser content of the
 *   node cannot hold the main body content.
```

I can't seem to access this variable. To test, I have a clean install of Drupal 8. In node.html.twig I have tried:

```
{% if readmore %}
<div>Some content</div>
{% endif %}
```

My 'Some content' text does not display regardless of whether the node's body is summary trimmed or not.

If I add `{{ dump(readmore) }}` it returns `null`. Again, regardless of whether or not the teaser is trimmed.

How do I access and use this 'readmore' variable?

Comment: What theme are you on ? Perhaps this behavior is specific to it. Try applying this to another core theme and report back what you observe.

Comment: Originally, I was developing a Bootstrap sub-theme when I noticed it did nothing, I then created a clean Drupal install and modified the Bartik core theme to test. Still nothing.

Comment: It sounds like this is only populated if the view mode is a teaser. But checking the Node module, it is added to the links array.

Comment: I am viewing my posts on the front page as teasers. I created 2 Articles. One is a few sentences long and doesn't truncate, the other is many paragraphs long and Drupal automatically truncates the body (as in 'teaser content of the node cannot hold the main body content.') which I interpret as an exact use case for the `readmore` variable. I would think in that `readmore` would be `true`. But according to dump() `readmore` doesn't even exist!

Comment: Also, I did a search on the entire Drupal 8.8 codebase and the string "readmore" doesn't exist anywhere in the code (besides these node.html.twig templates) which leads me to believe the documentation in this template is incorrect.